# how to send dynamically created text field value to php mail

Tags: javascript, php

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click( function(){
$val = $(this).val();
$('#container').html('');
$content = '';
$val = $(this).attr('count')
var i = 1;
for( i = 0; i < $val; i++ ) {
    $content += '<tr><td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="f1-email" placeholder="Name" class="f1-email form-control" id="f1-email"></div></td><td><div class="form-group input-sm"><input type="text" name="f1-email" maxlength="2"  placeholder="Age" class="f1-email form-control" id="f1-email"></div></td><td><div class="form-group"><select class="form-control"><option value="M" selected="">Male</option><option value="F">Female</option></select></div></td></tr>';
}
   $('#container').html($content);
 });
```

```html
<label>
<input  type="radio" name="optradio" value="1">1 
 PERSON
</label>
<label>
<input  type="radio" name="optradio" value="2" >2 
PERSON
</label>
<label>
<input  type="radio" name="optradio" value="3" >3 
PERSON
</label>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover table-striped mah">
<tbody id="container">

  </tbody>
 </table>
  </div>
```

i created text field using javascript depends on the usr radio button selection, how to get the values of dynamically created field value,i need to send these value to php mailer

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a way to send data through js to PHP, but since you want to retrieve that in php why not make it directly so?

Since is a form you can use the type of method of sending that data (POST OR GET) and getting it through php!

```
<form action="yourphpfile.php" method="post">
Some data: <input type="text" name="data">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

when someone clicks on submit it get's registered through PHP so if in your php code you use

```
 $_POST["data"]
```

You'll get the value of the input you've made

Comment: my web text field dynamically created based on user selection so how to post all the value of dynamically created text field

Comment: it doesn't matter, as soon as it gets submitted through POST it will receive it in the php.

Comment: that's really not related to the original question, if you have any other issues please search it up on google first... try to really understand what you should do before asking here on stack overflow. it may sounds rude but this community is not made to solve your problems. and believe me its better if you hear from me than from other users from this platform. Search it up the syntaxes of what you're doing. but answering no you cannot use the same name for 3 different text fields